# Replacing Content inside DIV Tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace content inside particular div tags (id="dd-header") with a comment. Tried several methods, and regular expressions. This is my latest try:

```
$html = preg_replace('/(<div\sid=\"dd\-header\">)[^<]+(<\/div>)/i', '<!-- Comment -->', $html);
```

Couldn't get it working. What am I doing wrong here?

**NOTE:** div tags further have multiple  tags

**Sample Code to Replace**

```
<div id="dd-header">
    <a id="logo-small" href="/" title="title"></a>
    <a href="http://url/">Link 1</a> | 
    <a href="javascript: (function () {window.location = 'http://url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);})()">Link 2</a>
    <!-- <a href="http://url">Image</a> | -->
    | <a href="url">Link 3</a></div>
```

Comment: Do you specifically have to do this with PHP or are you open to client-side solutions like Javascript?

Comment: Could you post the HTML that you are trying to manipulate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Comment: @Ankit see my actual solution

Comment: Which content inside the `div` are you trying to replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$html = preg_replace('/(<div\sid="dd-header">)([^<]|<.+>.*<\/.+>)+(<\/div>)/i', '$1<!-- Comment -->$3', $html);
```

see http://codepad.org/GpYkteh4

Comment: @hakre: yeah, it's quite hard with `preg_replace` and what if a tag is not closed correctly...but I've modified it a bit

Answer (score 2):

While in simple cases you can do this, as posted by rabudde, you can't do the general case with regular expressions.  It is a limitation of the regular expression language, and has been discussed extensively here on SO.

rabudde's code failes when a div contains sub-tags.

The correct way to do it is to parse the tree with an (X)HTML parser, find the div node, remove it's children, and replace with whatever you like.

Comment: I've modified my regex a bit, but sure, for complex content you'd better use a DOM parser

Answer (score 0):

Just use DOMDocument.  It'll parse it into a DOM that is ridiculously easy to traverse, search by ID, and manipulate.

See the documentation, starting with loadHTML: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php